# Should the tag wiki excerpt history be on the edit wiki page instead of 'learn more' page?

Tags: feature-request

Trying to be a good citizen, I recently made some edits to the `R` tag excerpt which turned out to be things that were not allowed.  I rolled back one, replaced it with something else that was not allowed, and someone else rolled that back. All good and well.  I was trying to figure out why I didn't know that similar edits had already been suggested and eventually rejected.

It turns out that info I could have used, the history of the wiki tag edits, is not on the edit wiki page, it is on the 'learn more' page.  Can it be both places, or be moved to the edit wiki page?  It's more relevant there.

Here is an image of where it is now, at the bottom of the 'learn more' page.  I am suggesting the 'excerpt history' link move to the edit wiki page.  Thanks for considering it.

[image: bottom of R learn more page]

Comment: For a start, the "excerpt history" should be placed more prominently.